# Generate random document from mongodb that lasts for 1 day

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am working on a quiz application using nodejs and mongodb. I want to introduce question of the day functionality where one random question gets generated for whole day and the questions changes on another day. I have written code to generate random question which is this:

```
exports.getRandomQuestion = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const count = await Question.countDocuments();
  // Get a random entry
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
  const question = await Question.findOne().skip(random).exec();
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: question,
  });
});
```

This generates a random question on every request.
How do I generate a random question that last for a day?

Comment: The functionality will need some kind of scheduler: A scheduled job (e.g., Linux `cron`) which runs every 24 hours, clears a collection called `dailyQuestion`and adds a question to a collection called as `dailyQuestion`. On a given day you can query this collection and get the same question.The collection can be a "capped" collection with `max` value set to `1`. (instead of a collection with one document, you can use a variable).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a TTL index for the `Question` collection.

```js
exports.createDailyQuestion = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {

     // Create the TTL index
     Question.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 86400 } 

     // The doc to be saved
     const examQuestion ={
        questionName: "Test Question 1"
        questionDescription: "Test Question ....."
        createdAt: new Date(),
     } 

    // Save the doc
    await new Community_DB(newCommunity).save()

   // Message to send to the front end
   res.status(200).send('Question Created')

});
```

The documents in this collection will be removed a day from when they are created.

If you don't want to have everything deleted in the whole collection, you have to write some code that automatically deleted the code based on the day created. You just have to subtract the `createdAt from Date.now()` to see if it's over a day old. But this is really not an efficient way because you will have to constantly check the DB for it and by the time you check it, the document might be a little bit more than a day depends on when you run the check.

Comment: I don't think this is right way to do this. You will end up with empty database if you don't add new documents frequently. Lets say you added 10k documents today, then all 10k documents will get removed the next day.

Comment: Because @user8747578 wants to add a question every day and have it deleted later on.

Comment: @AvivLo I don't want to delete the question. I just want another question on the next day. Like, I have about 10k questions on my database right now. I want to get a random question from those 10k questions and get another random question the other day.
I am thinking of building a separate route for this task and apply on my app.

Comment: Ok. So there was a misunderstanding. I thought you wanted to delete the question  because of the question: ' How do I generate a random question that lasts for a day'

Comment: The code I am writing above gives a random question for every api request. .skip skips some questions and gives another question on another request. Now, I need to generate question in the same way but that question need to remain for a day. In the next day, another question needs to appear.

Comment: So just change the value for skip

Comment: what about the date?

Comment: Just sort the DB chronologically. Run sort first then skip

Answer (score 0):

You can use redis cache. In your first req you will get question document right!!. then you have to save the question id in to your redis cache with expiry time based on your currentime. if you have the id in your cache dont hit random query. check in redis cache.. if you have an id in redis, get the id and query from mongodb.

You can `$sample` in mongodb for getting random records.
You have to maintain the key is date, value is question id. Everytime you have to query from there!!.

```
{
   "29-09-2020": "5ead1590635d8f0011ea5866",
   "30-09-2020": "5ead1590635d8f0011ea5867",
   ...
}
```

change into your query

```
db.getCollection('Questions').aggregate(
       [{ 
           $sample: { size: 2 } 
       }]
);
```

you will get the two random documents. check into your redis cache the last day id, you have to check the first obj in your arr with redis cache id. if there is equal. save the next one id!!. I thought it may be works fine!!